# template function to a function pointer inside a struct

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers

I wanted to use template function(s) referencing via its pointer using function pointer which is available inside a structure like

```
typedef struct arithmeticfunc {
          string funcName;
          int (*funPtr)(int,int);
};
```

For example:

```
int add(int a, int b)
    return (a+b);

int sub(int a, int b)
    return (a-b);

arithmeticfunc func[2] = { {"ADDITION", &add},
                           {"SUBTRACT", &sub} };

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    printf("Result of Function : %s is %d",func[i].funcName.c_str(),func[i]->funcPtr(2,1));
}
```

Now I need to use a template function instead of the normal static function.

Kindly let me know, am I doing on the right method.

Comment: What did you try to make your struct and functions templates? Where are you stuck with that? Please edit your question and show as sample, and the exact error messages.

Comment: In case you didn't realize it, much of the basic functionality you seem to be attempting to implement (associating a name with a function) is already provided by `std::map`/`std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin and their template functions already exist too [std::plus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/plus) and [std::minus](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/minus) among others

Comment: @CoryKramer: Good point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want your `struct` and functions to be templates?

```
template <typename T>
struct arithmeticfunc
{
    std::string funcName;
    T (*funPtr)(T, T);
};

template <typename T>
T add(T a, T b)
{
    return a+b;
}

template <typename T>
T sub(T a, T b)
{
    return a-b;
}
```

Then you could use them as follows

```
int main()
{
    arithmeticfunc<int> func[2] = { {"ADDITION", &add},
                                    {"SUBTRACT", &sub} };

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Result of Function : " 
                  << func[i].funcName
                  << " is "
                  << func[i].funPtr(2,1)
                  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note that you can no longer use the `%d` format code if you are using templates, because the type of `T` might not be an integer, it may be a `double`, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I need to know, what changes I need to undergo, if I move all the template functions into a separate header file (say tempFunc.h) and define the arthimeticfunc above main()?.. I tried on this way and getting no valid pointer for the function 'add'

Comment: whether we need to use &add to just add.. it works fine for both??!!